How to determine the concrete type of property value from a GenericEntity in hiconic.js?
How can I determine the type of a property value?
In my example, my class implements ManipulationListener and listens on ChangeValueManipulations.
I want to determine the concrete type of ChangeValueManipulation.newValue as it is any-typed.
What I want to achieve is to update an input field based on the given type (string, number or date).
